# aws cost explorer group by tag - no untaged?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Had a look around and couldn't find an exact answer or possible solution.

I'm in the AWS Cost Explorer and I have a report grouping by tag which works but doesn't include anything that's not tagged, is there a way to do this that anyone is aware of?

this isn't clear through the console or docs.